# Python Ctypes: Ctypes Struct is said to be missing attribute it has

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a ctype.LittleEndianStructure struct which contains a uint8, and two uint16's:

```
class VoltageTrigger(ctypes.LittleEndianStructure):
_pack_ = 1
_fields_ = [
    ("enabled",          ctypes.c_uint8),
    ("set",              ctypes.c_uint16),
    ("clear",            ctypes.c_uint16)
]
```

I have another struct whose members are all of the type "VoltageTrigger" as well:

```
class StringVoltageNotificationConfigurationPayload(ctypes.LittleEndianStructure):
_pack_ = 1
_fields = [
    ("highStringVoltageAlarm",           VoltageTrigger),
    ("lowStringVoltageAlarm",            VoltageTrigger),
    ("highStringVoltageWarning",         VoltageTrigger),
    ("lowStringVoltageWarning",          VoltageTrigger),
    ("highBatteryPackVoltageDeltaAlarm", VoltageTrigger),
    ("highBatteryPackVoltageDeltaWarning", VoltageTrigger)
]
```

Finally, I have one more struct, StringVoltageNotificationConfiguration_b,one of whose members is of type "StringVoltageNotificationConfigurationPayload"

```
class StringVoltageNotificationConfiguration_b(ctypes.LittleEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ("preamble",         CommandResponsePayloadPreamble),
        ("payload",          StringVoltageNotificationConfigurationPayload)
    ]
```

I build the VoltageTrigger() object like so:

```
def build_sc_voltageTrigger(enabled,set,clear):
    vT = VoltageTrigger()
    vT.enabled = enabled
    vT.set = set
    vT.clear = clear
    return vT
```

I try and build my SetStringVoltageNotificationConfigurationPayload object by directly assigning a VoltageTrigger() object to the members of SetStringVoltageNotificationConfigurationPayload(), and then I try and assign this SetStringVoltageNotificationConfigurationPayload object to the "payload" member of SetStringVoltageNotificationConfiguration_b():

```
stringVoltageAlarms_Warnings_Triggers = StringVoltageNotificationConfigurationPayload()
stringVoltageAlarms_Body = StringVoltageNotificationConfiguration_b()
stringVoltageAlarms_Warnings_Triggers.highStringVoltageAlarm = build_sc_voltageTrigger(1,300,200)
stringVoltageAlarms_Body.payload = stringVoltageAlarms_Warnings_Triggers
```

But stringVoltageAlarms_Body's payload member, which should be stringVoltageAlarms_Warnings_Triggers, which has the highStringVoltageAlarm member set to the VoltageTrigger type returned by the call to build_sc_voltageTrigger(1,300,200), is determined to not even have the attribute 'highStringVoltageAlarm' although the interpreter doesn't complain when I set it the highStringVoltageAlarm member. When I do:

```
print(stringVoltageAlarms_Body.payload.highStringVoltageAlarm.set)
```

I get the error from the interpreter:

```
AttributeError: 'StringVoltageNotificationConfigurationPayload' object has no attribute 'highStringVoltageAlarm'
```

Why does the StringVoltageNotificationConfigurationPayload object be said to have no attribute 'highStringVoltageAlarm'? I was even able to set it without issue, but trying to actually print it out as a member of SetStringVoltageNotificationConfiguration_b() the intepreter says it doesn't even exist as an attribute?

Comment: Next time make a [mcve], which is a single block of code that can be cut/paste/run without changes and reproduce the issue.  But in this case it is just a typo.  `_fields_` is misspelled `_fields`  in `StringVoltageNotificationConfigurationPayload` so the fields aren't created correctly.  Voting to close as a typo.